# Photodiode driver circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis

I got a circuit for a photodiode, but unfortunately without datasheet and explanation. Now I am a bit confused what the purpose of the different parts is:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fyYZjI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

As far as I understood, the resistor R1 and the diode D1 are providing a voltage drop, while the capacitor C1 provides a voltage buffer. R2 is doing ?, and C2 is coupling out DC current. Is that correct? And what is the purpose of R2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The photodiode has some parasitic capacitance. Its time constant is hence C times the load resistance. R2 plays the role of this load here; a sufficiently small value such that the response time will be acceptable for whatever application this circuit is intended. It also converts the output current into a voltage, thus giving the circuit a definite gain (200 V/A) independent of the load (within reason).

C2 also needs not to be fully charged if it is to work as a coupling capacitor, and R2 allows for that to happen by providing a d.c. path to ground.